# Parallel installation of Office 2003 and Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-365, outlook-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

we have a customer who is not willing to move from Office 2003 to Office 2010 but he now wants to use Office 365. As you know is Office 365 not compatible with Outlook 2003.

Now he asked me if it's possible to buy and install Outlook 2010 and keep the rest as it is.

I only found some guides for parallel installation of Office 2007 and Office 2010.

So my question is if this solution will work. Or are there any issues known?

Answer (score 1):

I found in the [MSFT KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121447/) the necessary information's.

Summary: It's possible but not recommended from MSFT.

Comment: Maybe you can flag that answer then as "answer" so that it didn´t come up in the open questions ;-)